# error occurs when I try to pass a list to my class attributes

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I'm trying to pass a list to my class attributes using classmethod:

```
class BASE_MODEL(object):
    def __init__(self, train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels):
        self.train_data, self.train_labels, self.val_data, self.val_labels = \
            train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels

    @classmethod
    def list_to_data(cls, data_list):
        train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels = data_list
        data = cls(train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels)
        return data

class Fine_Tune_Model(BASE_MODEL):
    def __init__(self, fine_tune_at=None):
        super(BASE_MODEL, self).__init__()
        self.fine_tune_at = fine_tune_at

fine_tune_model = Fine_Tune_Model.list_to_data(data_lsit)
```

This works fine for the superclass。

However when I try to pass the same function to the subclass, an error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Studium/Thesis/Fine_Tuning.py", line 138, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:/Studium/Thesis/Fine_Tuning.py", line 133, in main
    fine_tune_model = Fine_Tune_Model.list_to_data(create_data.split_data(3000, 200))
  File "E:\Studium\Thesis\Train.py", line 32, in list_to_data
    data = cls(train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 5 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is it because I get one more parameter 'fine_tune_at' in my subclass? If so, how can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find where the problem is:

```
class BASE_MODEL(object):
    def __init__(self, train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels):
        self.train_data, self.train_labels, self.val_data, self.val_labels = \
            train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels

    @classmethod
    def list_to_data(cls, data_list):
        train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels = data_list
        data = cls(train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels)
        return data

class Fine_Tune_Model(BASE_MODEL):
    def __init__(self, train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels):
        super(Fine_Tune_Model, self).__init__(train_data, train_labels, val_data, val_labels)
        self.fine_tune_at = fine_tune_at

fine_tune_model = Fine_Tune_Model.list_to_data(data_lsit)
```

I didn't properly inherit the attributes in the superclass.